# debug wrapper for external functions

Tags: python, decorator, jython

I am looking for a way to simultaneously print and execute a function/method in a similar I could do by wrapping a function. The issue is that I can not directly decorate the function as the function I am calling is part of a jython module.
So I have something along the lines

```
from jythonModule import fun, obj

fun(a,b,c)
o = obj
o.method(e,f)
```

I am looking for away to run and print the code
So it would show

fun(a,b,c)
o.method(e,f)

and execute those commands.
How could I do that without having access to the jython module?
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`sys.settrace`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.settrace):

```
# trace.py
import sys


def trace_function(frame, event, arg):
    if event == "call":  # Only report function calls
        code_name = frame.f_code.co_name
        code = frame.f_code
        print "Function call: {0} @ {1}:{2}".format(code.co_name, code.co_filename, code.co_firstlineno)
        print "Locals:", frame.f_locals
        print
    return trace_function  # Continue tracing the new scope



def f0(arg):
    print "In f0: ", arg
    print "Done"

def f1(arg):
    print "In f1: ", arg
    f0(arg)

def f2(arg):
    print "In f2: ", arg
    f1(arg)


sys.settrace(trace_function)


f2("The arg string")
```

Will give you the following output:

```
$ python trace.py:
Function call: f2 @ trace.py:23
Locals: {'arg': 'The arg string'}

In f2:  The arg string
Function call: f1 @ trace.py:19
Locals: {'arg': 'The arg string'}

In f1:  The arg string
Function call: f0 @ trace.py:15
Locals: {'arg': 'The arg string'}

In f0:  The arg string
Done
Function call: _remove @ /Users/thomas/.virtualenvs/ec2vpn/lib/python2.7/_weakrefset.py:38
Locals: {'item': <weakref at 0x106743158; dead>, 'selfref': <weakref at 0x1067956d8; to 'WeakSet' at 0x1067949d0>}

Function call: _remove @ /Users/thomas/.virtualenvs/ec2vpn/lib/python2.7/_weakrefset.py:38
Locals: {'item': <weakref at 0x1067430a8; dead>, 'selfref': <weakref at 0x106743050; to 'WeakSet' at 0x106744e90>}
```